# UserControls Base Class not found in NameSpace

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I'm currently stuck with this weird behaviour of Visual Studio

I've got this Base Class here:

```
namespace IntelliListDemo.Controls
{
public class NodeControlBase : UserControl
{
    public NodeControlBase(NotYetGenericOutputNode internalNode)
    {
        this._internalNode = internalNode;
    }
    public NodeControlBase() { }
}
}
```

And i have some controls deriving from it. An Example:

```
namespace IntelliListDemo.Controls
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für Source.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SourceControl : NodeControlBase//, ISourceControl, INodeControl
{
    public SourceControl(IntelliListLibrary.Nodes.SourceNode internalNode) : base(internalNode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Controls:NodeControlBase x:Class="IntelliListDemo.Controls.SourceControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:IntelliListDemo.Controls"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
       >
</Controls:NodeControlBase>
```

So I always get compiler Errors saying

> The name "NodeControlBase" does not exist in Namespace
>   "clr-namespace:IntelliListDemo.Controls".

Comment: Does `SourceNode` and `NotYetGenericOutputNode` have any relation between them?

Comment: @RohitVats Yes, SourceNode derives from NotYetGenericOutputNode. In between are some generic Classes.

Answer (score 1):

Found this old question when I had the same problem. Turned out I had a syntax error in my XAML code in another file that was preventing the build completing, and so the reference to the base class could not be resolved.

The way I tracked it down was commenting out the code related to the base UserControl class and making sure I had a clean compile - and being sure to check *all* the derived views when I re-introduced the new code!